# WPF UserControl doesn't capture events after being reloaded

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an application where I have a custom UserControl inside a TabControl. Every so often the whole app needs to refresh it's data. To handle it, I'm doing the following in the code-behind.

```
    public void OnDataReloaded(object a)
    {
        WindowManager.GraphControl = new GraphControl();
        GraphTab.Content = WindowManager.GraphControl;
        graphloaded = true;
    }
```

GraphTab is an instance of TabItem in my TabControl. WindowManager is a static class that handles references to currently active User Controls.
On my UserControl, I have added an event handler: KeyDown="MyGraphControl_KeyDown_1" as a property to the UserControl.

After I execute the code above, everything works as expected. My TabControl loads the new UserControl, however keydown events aren't being captured anymore. Any idea why that might be the case?

Thanks!

Comment: did you bind Keydown on the initial instance of your GraphControl (constructor/load etc) and because you are loading a new instance, it's no longer bound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not 100% sure but my best guess is that because its a new instance of a GraphControl - the Events would have been destroyed or are still in linked to the old instance of the control in Memory.

Before you give it a new instance, make sure you un subscribe to the events and also try re pointing the event handlers to your methods.

Hope that helps!

ste.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to KeyDown event in your OnDataReloaded method. You create there a new instance of your control, whereas your KeyDown in XAML applies only to the first instance created.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code it's hard to give any definitive answers but one possibility is that your old key down handler is still getting executed. Depending on what that handler does, it may be blocking WPF from sending further key down events to other code.

If you're not un-assigning the event handler on the old user control when you replace it, it will continue to be executed.

That's all pure guesswork of course, it might be something else completely!